# Retrieve dataTable object of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to get an object of a jQuery Data Table using JQuery. I am using this thread to accomplish this:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2913/how-to-get-the-otable-datatable-object-from-the-tables-id

For some reason this does not work. When I call `$('.dynamic-wide-table').dataTable();` it causes my table to initialize AGAIN and make the table render twice, like so:

[image]

According to the link posted above it should NOT be doing that, but instead just fetch the object.

Here is my code:

`main.js` (loaded into HTML head of every page)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dynamic-wide-table").dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 530,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, -1],
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, "All"]
        ],
        "retrieve": true
    });
});
```

get object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dynamic-wide-table').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: Which object are you trying to get?

Comment: The datatables object.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments:

You wont be able to get the single tables object because each element with that class will have it's own `dataTable` object.

You could loop through the classes and retrieve each individual one. In order to get a single elements `dataTable` object you will need to know which table element it is that you need the object from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dynamic-wide-table').each(function(i){
        console.log('table no. ' + i );
        // Should print the dataTable object for each element to the console
        console.log($(this).dataTable());
    });
});
```

The ideal thing to do would be to give each individual table an id, then retrieve the `dataTable` object with the id:

```
$('#tableId').dataTable();
```

Comment: I can not set the variable in `main.js` because I have multiple tables on multiple pages. In other words, one variable can not reference multiple tables on a page. Therefore I need to retrieve the object on each page itself when needed.

Comment: So you instantiate it into one variable per table. Then each variable will contain the object which you call functions on to perform actions on that table.

Comment: Every page has a different amount of tables and I can't programatically know how many are on a given page.

Comment: @Nic you have to instantiate each table though otherwise they wont render?

Comment: Yea, that's why I reference via a class name. So the object will be created for every table on a given page. On certain pages I need to access the datatables object though which is why I want to do what I am doing.

Comment: Okay, so that one call instantiates multiple tables on all elements with that class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And on particular pages I want to access the object associated with one or more of the tables. If I set the initialization equal to a variable then every table on a given page will have the same variable name, which will not work.

Comment: @Nic i edited the answer, also that forum you linked specifies that using .dataTable() on an element doesn't return the object unless you are on a version newer that 1.6

Comment: @Nic Did that help?

Answer (score -1):

Mmm I don't think you need to set both..?

If you remove the get object code it should stop firing twice.

You are already doing this in `main.js` , but loading options at the same time.

Comment: Terrible answer. Does not address what I want whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry I got it from - "it causes my table to initialize AGAIN and make the table render twice" | my mistake.