# Can't destroy() jQuery Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am having an issue with trying to destroy a JQuery Data Table.

Here is where I initialize it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $(".dynamic-wide-table").DataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 530,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, -1],
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, "All"]
        ],
        "retrieve": true
    });
});
```

Here is where I try to destroy it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // Note that my page has two tables on it!
    table.destroy();
    table[0].destroy();
});        // Trying to delete both tables first, then just the first table
```

Here are my errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: table.destroy is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: table[0].destroy is not a function
```

Does anybody know what's going on?! I'm very confused.

**Edit**:

Here is an image of what happens when I console.log `table`.

[image]

Comment: It's working! https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/79/

Comment: Mine selects by class and also are initiated and destroyed in separate files. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Like described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486062/retrieve-datatable-object-of-element/38486244), you should use ID's to get the dataTable object and call function on it: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63qhddxx/)

Comment: I cannot use ids because I have multiple tables per page and I will not know what the ids are at the time of initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate the tables with an each() loop and store them in an array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var tables = [];

    $("table").each(function(i){
     var table = $(this).DataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 530,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, -1],
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, "All"]
        ],
        "retrieve": true
    });
    tables.push(table);
    });

    $('#button').click( function () {
        // Then you can call destroy on that object
        var elem = tables[0].table().node();
        tables[0].destroy();
        // And empty the element
        $(elem).empty()
    } );
} );
```

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49tfrhct/2/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].DataTable is not a function

Comment: @Nic calls destroy on table instances

Comment: I had to move `tables` out so it was global but otherwise this works beautifully. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. although there was only one table in my page, but I'd got error:

```js
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tbl.destroy is not a function
```

the reason for me was because instead of initializing dataTable like:

```
let tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

I'd wrote it as:

```
let tbl = $('#myTable').dataTable();
```

please notice to write `.DataTable` with capital `D`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can't both create and destroy a DataTable within `$(document).ready()`, since those events are triggered at the same time. See @CMedina's [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/79/) where he shows that they work when triggered by, say, a button click. (Assuming these are in the same file)</s> Ignore this part; apparently they are different files.

Note that you said in a comment that the creation/destroy are in different files. If that's indeed the case, how is the destroying file made aware of `table`? If it's not aware of the DataTable (which could also be caused by not including the script file on that page) then it won't know what `destroy()` does, and throw an error.

**Edit:** I just noticed that you are trying to use `destroy()` on `table` and then on `table[0]`. You can't have `table` be a DataTable and also an array of DataTables. Try naming your tables uniquely or both in arrays; either

```
var table;
table[0] = $('#example').DataTable();
table[1] = $('#example2').DataTable();
```

Or (probably better)

```
var table1 = $('#example').DataTable();
var table2 = $('#example').DataTable();
```

Comment: `main.js`, which includes the creation of the data table is included in the head section of the HTML page that the destroy function is on.

Comment: I've added an onclick like @CMedina's JSfiddle. I get `Uncaught TypeError: table[0].destroy is not a function` for an error. Also tried without an index and got `Uncaught TypeError: table.destroy is not a function`.

Comment: Added an image of what happens when I print `table` to the console.

Comment: @Nic Is the DataTables script file included on the page the destroy function is on?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have 2 datatables in your page, and your initializacion is for all tables with the class `.dynamic-wide-table`.

For destroy only one table you should get all datatables in your page with [tables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.tables()) function.

Then apply destroy to specified table: (In my example work with 2 datatables).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $(".dynamic-wide-table").DataTable({
    "aaSorting": [],
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": 530,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "lengthMenu": [
        [100, 400, 1000, 5000, -1],
        [100, 400, 1000, 5000, "All"]
    ],
    "retrieve": true
});


$('#destroy1').click( function () {
    var dt1 = $.fn.dataTable.tables()[0];
    $(dt1).DataTable().destroy();
} );

$('#destroy2').click( function () {
 var dt2 = $.fn.dataTable.tables()[1];
    $(dt2).DataTable().destroy();
} );
} );
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/80/

Comment: `$.fn.dataTable.tables()` only contains one table for some reason. However, `console.log(table)` contains 2. @CMedina . It does work however, for deleting 1 table.

Comment: Please post your code to help! (HTML + JS) complete!

Comment: Each table is in its own bootstrap tab. Could that be the reason it only finds one table? @CMedina

Comment: Yeah its the reason, the  tab active hide the others.elements